# Best way to check web-responsiveness

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, responsive-design, localhost

I am wondering if there is a way to check website responsiveness without uploading my code to a host site. I have all of my files and code in VSCODE and I have tested it out through shrinking the browser etc but I actually want to see my site on different devices before I upload my code. Because everything is local to my device I can't think of an easy way to do this without actually uploading everything? Any ideas?

Comment: localhost is enough or docker container

Comment: This could be what your looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992/12962579

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I assume that you already have the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension installed in your vscode IDE and you are able to open your website on the web browser on the same computer*

There's an extension for vs code called [MobileView](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cirlorm.mobileview)
You can check your local websites as well as global ones just copy and paste there the website link. But it is limited just to three mobile devices (iphone X, 8 and google pixel). You can open all three previews at the same time in different tabs.

But it additionally allows you to check how your site's design will fit to the phones real exterior (its color and shapes).

And of course you can open your website on the real mobile phone if your vscode computer and the mobile phone are on the same wifi network.